# Как сделать  в центре  (отвыкаю от таблиц)?

Tags: html, css

Код: http://jsfiddle.net/Zajkm/

Хотелось бы сделать .slider И весь контент (ul) в середине, не могу понять, всё перепробовал.

Comment: margin: 0 auto; ??

Comment: не помогает к сож(

Comment: вы правы, сделайте ответом я приму как правильный. спаисбо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вы верстаете списком страницу? Не лучше ли сделать это по-человечески div'ами?
Не очень понятно что вы хотите выровнять по середине, но вот слайдер и страница выровненные  по середине : http://jsfiddle.net/JjLsd/

Вот пример вёрстки блоками(не идеал конечно, но и делал на скорую руку): http://jsfiddle.net/TMfJj/

Несколько советов(ИМХО):

- margin и padding равные 0лю задавайте через *{} сразу для всех элементов, а не отдельно прописывайте для каждого.
- картинки я бы брал в .jpg формате адаптированном под Web, но в вашем случае это конечно не критично...
- не используйте в вёрстке атрибуты у тегов, для этого у вас есть css (я про width и height в вашем коде)

Comment: спасибо милый человек!

Answer (score 1):

```
<center>
<div class="slider">
<div class="mslide">
<img src="art/slide1.png" width="650" height="240">
</div>
<div class="mbut">
<img src="art/but1.png" width="250" height="80">
<img src="art/but2.png" width="250" height="80">
<img src="art/but3.png" width="250" height="80">
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li>main text</li>
<li>footer</li>
</ul>
    </center>
Попробавал - работает!
```

Comment: да это работает, но w3 валидатор не пускает тег center

Comment: Ну и забей на него! Зачем тебе этот консорциум? Прверь гугл или хешкод через валидатор все одно будут ошибки!)

Comment: Ошибки:
Яндекс 184
Google 24
hashcode 5

http://www.validome.org/get/http://google.ru

Answer (score 0):

Почему же? margin:0 auto; работает всегда, но только для элементов с фиксированной шириной